# Object oriented programming with abstract class

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns

I want to achieve the below:

```
def do_something(request):
    company_name = request.get("company_name", DEFAULT_COMPANY)
    data = request.get("data")
    response = transform_data_according_to(data, company_name)
    return response
```

I did the following for it:

```
class Transform(ABC):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    @abstractmethod
    def transform(self):
        pass

class CompanyA(Transform):
    def transform(self):
        # do_transformation
        return transformed_data

def do_something(request):
    company_name = request.get("company_name", DEFAULT_COMPANY)
    data = request.get("data")
    if company_name == CompanyA:
        response = CompanyA.transform(data)
    return response
```

Instead i would like to do something like this using correct object oriented principles:

```
def do_something(request):
    company_name = request.get("company_name", DEFAULT_COMPANY)
    data = request.get("data")
    response = Transform(data, company_name)
    return response
```

I want to know where I might be thinking wrong in terms of the desired approach versus the implemented approach. Is the implemented approach correct, the if else checks can grow quite big in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [teraflop](https://www.reddit.com/user/teraflop/)

The simple, idiomatic way to do this in Python would be to look up the Transform subclass in a dictionary:

```
transform_classes = {
    "CompanyA": CompanyA,
    # ...
}

def do_something(request):
    company_name = request.get("company_name", DEFAULT_COMPANY)
    data = request.get("data")
    transformer = transform_classes[company_name](data)
    return transformer.transform()
```

If you prefer to be more rigorously object-oriented, you could wrap the dictionary in an object (e.g. `TransformLookupByName`) instead of accessing it directly.

There are also various kinds of metaprogramming magic you can use to build the dictionary automatically without having to name each subclass explicitly. For example, this will collect all of the `Transform` subclasses in the current source file:

```
transform_classes = {
    k:v for k,v in globals().items() 
        if isinstance(v, type) and issubclass(v, Transform) and v != Transform
}
```